# Unable to login to arch linux

Tags: arch-linux

I am new to archlinux. I am using live usb for archlinux. When I booted it said `not a COM32R image`. I explored on Google, used Tab and choose `have64` and then it booted.

Now I am not able to login I used password `root` but it's not accepting. I also used `startx` but nothing happened. I am using `archlinux-2014.06.01-dual` iso downloaded from [archlinux website](https://www.archlinux.org/download/).

I see the the following **Arch Linux Menu** after boot-up

```
 Boot Arch Linux (x86_64)(NBD)
 Boot Arch Linux (x86_64)(NFS)
 Boot Arch Linux (x86_64)(HTTP)
 Boot Arch Linux (i686)(NBD)
 Boot Arch Linux (i686)(NFS)
 Boot Arch Linux (i686)(HTTP)
 Boot Existing OS
```

I tried First and fourth Options (NBD) for live boot and I am having the problem mentioned as above.

Comment: What you have downloaded is the "live" distro.

Comment: @p1xel then how can i solve the problem

Comment: I am not entirely sure, however is appears you either have a corrupted ISO or the way you made the Live USB corrupted it. Arch Linux is supposed to automatically login as root at boot. Also, more details such as what your computer is (if it has UEFI etc.) and how you made the Live USB would help others answer the question.

Comment: using Universal USB Installer by Pendrive Linux.

Comment: [**NBD**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_block_device) comes from "Network Block Device" and it's probably used for booting from the Internet just like the NFS and HTTP options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iso you are attempting to boot can be used for three things: installation, system maintenance, and recovery purposes. To run instead a full-fledged Arch system, you will have to install Arch Linux onto a USB key. This will be just a regular install, with, furthermore, the added advantage that any modification you make to the system (from package installation to choice of background wallpaper) will be permanent.

There is plenty of information on how to that [on this Arch Linux Wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installing_Arch_Linux_on_a_USB_key). Notice, you will need a USB of at least 2GB, which, as you can see, is considerably larger than the installation iso, 500 MB or so.

Comment: thank you for your answer. It really helped me. I went through some YouTube videos and sorted out problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since I have lesser rep. can't post as comment:

Like @p1xel pointed out did you try to check whether ISO is corrupted or not.

From the archlinux download link:
Checksums
File integrity checksums for the latest releases can be found below:

```
PGP signature
MD5: 6539a93751c388db424b2600290a2b4f
SHA1: 61bfd735e62336a800d27a94e3e55d5bbe99d6bf
```

md5sum "/pathtopackage" or sha1sum "/pathtopackage"
and check for the above.

Also, you pointed out using "startx" but no desired results. Are you able to get the prompt to run startx? Share the syslog if feasible for troubleshoot. Also details of your system would be useful.

Comment: I have downloaded from https://www.archlinux.org/download/ Indian download link and the checksums file intefgrity are same as you have given.